# Create a list to display historical form entries

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a simple excel database with VB to track weekly hours against various projects. This is my first venture at trying VB so a little out of the water on this.

I wish to utilize a list box to display the historical entries for a specific worksheet "Weeklyhours".

How can I define the RowSource range of cells for the list data. I'm assuming 1 - find the last row, define the first row. I worked that out, but I am now stuck as to the correct formatting.

Here's my code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
'activateSheet(Weeklyhours As String)    
'Sheets(Weeklyhours).Select      
'ActiveSheet.Range("I2").Select = TxtMonhours.Text      
'ActiveSheet.Range("j2").Select = TxtTueshours.Text      
Dim Total As Double    
'Make sure correct worksheet is selected to store data    
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Weeklyhours").Activate    

'Find last row and define first row    
LastRow = Worksheets("Weeklyhours").Cells(65000, 9).End(xlUp).Row    
FirstRow = Worksheets("Weeklyhours").Cells(2, 9).Row    

'MsgBox FirstRow    
'MsgBox LastRow    
'input data for Mon thru Sun    
Cells(LastRow + 1, 8).Value = txtweek.Text    
Cells(LastRow + 1, 9).Value = TxtMonhours.Text      
Cells(LastRow + 1, 10).Value = TxtTuehours.Text    
Cells(LastRow + 1, 11).Value = TxtWedhours.Text    
Cells(LastRow + 1, 12).Value = TxtThurhours.Text    
Cells(LastRow + 1, 13).Value = Txtfrihours.Text    
Cells(LastRow + 1, 14).Value = txtSathrs.Text    
Cells(LastRow + 1, 15).Value = txtSunhrs.Text    

'Calculate total hours todate and remaining hours      
Total = Application.Sum(Sheets("Weeklyhours").Range("Q3:Q1000"))    

txtweektotal.Text = Cells(LastRow + 1, 17)    
txthoursused.Text = Total    
txthrsavail.Text = txtPOhours.Value - Total    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Discovered the solution. Need to use the Me.listbox2 command.

```
Me.ListBox2 ' ListBox2 = name of listBox
.ColumnCount = x ' substitute x for variable eg. 1, 2, 4 etc
.Column Widths = "xx; yy"  ' made sure to account for all columns - i.e 2 columns at 50 px width will read "50;50"
.Rowsource = Sheets(SheetName).Range("a1:c10").Address
```